# Json Filter Objects Into Different Array

Tags: node.js, json, sorting, leaderboard

Let's Say I Have This user data under

```
{
  "asdfasdf": {
    "user": "asdfasdf",
    "skillpoints": 0,
    "acc": 0,
    "sessions": 0,
    "wpm": 0
  },
  "matthewproskils": {
    "user": "matthewproskils",
    "skillpoints": 0,
    "acc": 0,
    "sessions": 0
  }
}
```

Is there any way to sort this data into an 3 arrays?
I want the arrays to have a result of [[matthewproskils, 0],[asdfasdf, 0]]

Comment: Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you example seems to only have 2 Keys within the original JSON.

But if you want to Create an array of keys and array of contents you can

```
const jsonObject = {
  "asdfasdf": {
    "user": "asdfasdf",
    "skillpoints": 0,
    "acc": 0,
    "sessions": 0,
    "wpm": 0
  },
  "matthewproskils": {
    "user": "matthewproskils",
    "skillpoints": 0,
    "acc": 0,
    "sessions": 0
  }
}

let keys= [];
let keyContents = [];

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(jsonObject)) {
  keys.push(key);
  keyContents.push(value);
}
```

it will output

```
keys = ['asdfasdf','matthewproskils']
keyContents [{
        "user": "matthewproskils",
        "skillpoints": 0,
        "acc": 0,
        "sessions": 0
      },{
    "user": "matthewproskils",
    "skillpoints": 0,
    "acc": 0,
    "sessions": 0
  }];
```